# What is the difference between using unawaited and not using unawaited in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I've just stumbled upon a github repo containing an example of flutter application for google_sign_in package.

I'm confused about a particular usage of *unawaited* used inside the example :

```
Future<void> _handleAuthorizeScopes() async {
    final bool isAuthorized = await _googleSignIn.requestScopes(scopes);
    setState(() {
      _isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
    });
    if (isAuthorized) {
      unawaited(_handleGetContact(_currentUser!)); // --> this code
    }
  }
```

What confusing me is what's the difference between that and not using the unawaited function, i.e:

```
Future<void> _handleAuthorizeScopes() async {
    final bool isAuthorized = await _googleSignIn.requestScopes(scopes);
    setState(() {
      _isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
    });
    if (isAuthorized) {
      _handleGetContact(_currentUser!); // --> this code is changed
    }
  }
```

What I expect was that the result between the two approaches (using and not using *unawaited*) is the same, however if that's the case, then I'm even more confused of the need of the *unawaited* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helps with linter messages, from the docs:

> Explicitly ignores a future.
>
> Not all futures need to be awaited. The Dart linter has an optional
> "unawaited futures" lint which enforces that potential futures
> (expressions with a static type of Future or Future?) in asynchronous
> functions are handled somehow. If a particular future value doesn't
> need to be awaited, you can call unawaited(...) with it, which will
> avoid the lint, simply because the expression no longer has type
> Future. Using unawaited has no other effect. You should use unawaited
> to convey the intention of deliberately not waiting for the future.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/unawaited.html